# Regex to match any word that does not start with a capital letter

Tags: regex, cpu-word

I need a regex to match the description in the title.

Just for background, I need to be able to process a text in a regex-able text processor (notepad++, libreoffice writer) so that all words that start in lowercase disappear (are replaced with nothing). The remaining words will be processed further to become tags for the text.

Thanks a lot

UPDATE: if possible, this should work with unicode charcaters not just ASCII. There are only a few chracters that need to be considered, mainly î,ș

Update 2
\W\l(\w*) will replace any word starting in lowercase
[[:punct:]] will cleanup the additional punctuation that remains

This works in notepad++

Comment: Well, that would replace all characters. However [a-z]\w*\s will produce good results.Thank you so much. Still, this works with ASCII not unicode. I will edit the question so maybe someone can suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which flavor of regular expressions you're using, but assuming the most common, this should do it:

```
/b[a-z]+
```

Comment: Not sure how many flavors there are. I am using whatever flavor notepad++ and LibreOffice writer use (and i know they are somewhat different). Anyway, your wxpresion did not work in either software

Comment: Then they're not using UNIX regex, which I'd say is closest to a standard there is.

Answer (score 0):

This code will replace all words with nothing if they start with lower capital:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^([a-z]{1})(\w*)", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not really a programmer. I tried to use find and replace in Notepad++ and "^([a-z]{1})(\w*)" matches all words that simultaneuously start with a capital and are on the beginning of a line. Now, i could force all words on separate lines (more or less). But the expression still finds the oposite of what I want it to find

Comment: correction: it matches all words at the beginning of the line. It was the word wrap that led me to believe otherwise :)